# Wordpress: Redirect Main Site to Subsite in Multisite Where user is NOT logged in

Tags: php, redirect

I have found this solution ( [https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66115/redirect-main-site-to-subsite-in-multisite-wordpress )](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/66115/redirect-main-site-to-subsite-in-multisite-wordpress) regarding redirecting a mainsite to a subsite in wordpress.

But!

What IF I only want this to happen when a user is not logged in ?
I tried to change the code to this, but without any success..

```
  <?php
function wpse66115_redirect_to_sub_site() { 
  if ( is_user_logged_in() && is_main_site() ) {
    exit( wp_redirect( 'http://old.heiledeg.no', 301 ) );
  }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse66115_redirect_to_sub_site' );
?>
```

I also tried using an ELSE statement.
But it seems the argument ignores the "is_user_logged_in" argument.

Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
function wpse66115_redirect_to_sub_site() { 
  if ( is_main_site() ) {
      if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
      } else {
        exit( wp_redirect( 'http://old.heiledeg.no', 301 ) );
      }
  }
}
add_action( 'parse_request', 'wpse66115_redirect_to_sub_site' );
```

Comment: thank you. It seems to be working now.

Comment: you are welcome